# Add Message to Azure Queue when Azure Table Storage is updated

Tags: azure

Currently, I have an Azure Function App which runs every hour (timer trigger) that pulls data from Azure table storage and updates a NSG. I only did it this way because Function Apps currently DON'T support Azure Table triggers; however Function Apps DO support Azure queue triggers.

With that said, i'd like a message be sent to the queue every time my Azure Table is updated. That way, the Azure Table updates can happen immediately compared to every hour. Haven't figured out how to send messages to Azure Queue from Azure Tables though.

Any help?

Comment: There is no built-in way to get a message upon updating Azure Tables. Only Azure Blobs are wired that way (via Event Grid). You'd need to manage this yourself (e.g. push a message to a queue after writing to an Azure Table, or maybe just writing the "update" command into a queue, and then having an Azure Function take care of the Table update and any other downstream notifications).

Answer (score 0):

There is no change feed, update triggers etc. on Azure Table storage. You could achieve this by switching to Tables API on Cosmos DB - which does have a Change Feed.

Comment: Thanks, considered Cosmos DB but we are hosting an extremely small amount of data. The cost associated to Cosmos DB wouldn't make sense in this scenario,

Comment: @BoyArmy_89 look at the new serverless option of CosmosDB https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/